# What is an NDR-Pair?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I can find sources that tell me explicitly what an NDR-pair is in terms of a map and a homotopy, but is there a good intuitive idea corresponding to, or some canonical examples that I might be able to investigate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this article to be helpful:  http://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/examples-of-cofibrations/

Basically, $(X, A)$ is an NDR-pair when there is an open $U \supset A$  (a neighborhood of $A$) such that  $A$ is a deformation-retract of $U$.  If $A$ is closed in $X$, then this is equivalent to the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ being a cofibration.

I believe the most useful and ubiquitous examples (to an algebraic topologist) are CW-pairs $(X, A)$.

Comment: This isn't quite correct - in an NDR pair the deformation retraction of U onto A is also extended to a continuous homotopy of maps defined on all of X, and there is also a function $u: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ which is zero precisely on A and for which $U = u^{-1}([0,1))$. If you want an intuitive characterization that implies all of this, you can assume that $A \subset X$ has a *regular neighborhood*, which is a closed neighborhood that is homeomorphic to the mapping cylinder of some map $B \rightarrow A$.