# Good pair vs. cofibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

It can [be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512743/showing-continuity-of-partially-defined-map) that $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ is a closed cofibration if and only if there is a map $\varphi:X\to I=[0,1]$ and a homotopy $H:U\times I\to X$ on some neighborhood $U$ of $A$ such that

- $A=φ^{-1}(0)$ and $φ^{-1}([0,1))\subseteq U$
- $H(x,0)=x$, $H(a,t)=a$, and $H(x,1)\in A$ for all $x\in U, a\in A, t\in I$.

The last condition says that the neighborhood $U$ is deformable in $X$ to $A$. However, this seems to be different from $U$ deformation retracting to $A$ since the path $H(\{x\}×I)$ need not stay in $U$.

We can call $(X,A)$ a *good pair* (terminology from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*) if $A$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and some neighborhood $V$ deformation retracts to $A$.

I'd be interested to see an example of a closed cofibration which is not a good pair. Such an example would feature a neighborhood $U$ of $A$ whose inclusion in $X$ is homotopic to a retraction onto $A$ but for no neighborhood such a homotopy would stay within that set. At first I thought you could simply replace $U$ be the larger set $V=H[U\times I]$ and for each point $y\in V$ let the path start at $t_y$ the smallest point in time such that some $y=H(x,t_y)$ for some $x$ in $U$, and let $y$ be attached to $x$ on its path towards $A$, but this doesn't always give a well-defined map. In other words, the deformable neighborhood does not always give rise to a neighborhood which deformation retracts to $A$.

Of course if someone comes up with a good pair which is not cofibered, that would be nice, too.

Comment: I think that you are missing assumption about closeness of $A$. If so taking your assumptions about closed cofibration one may call pair $(A,X)$ [*neighbourhood deformation retract*](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/ndr.pdf). Then [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51282/what-is-an-ndr-pair#comment1510613_51285) answer and comment bellow it may be useful in further research.

Comment: @StephenDedalus I don't understand the comment.  It seems like this is not really addressed in May or Hatcher, and I don't see anything helpful at the linked answer or in the blog post linked to therein.  (That blog post says something about U deformation retracting to A, but just as in May's book that's not really part of the statement.)  Arne Strom's papers Notes on Cofibrations I and II say more clearly that U is deformable to A *in X* rather than saying that U deformation retracts to A.

Comment: Practically speaking, the important thing is to know that a cofibration induces a LES on homology (involving the homologies of A, X, and X/A).  This can be seen by noting that the the inclusion of CA into the mapping cone Ci is a cofibration (it's obtained from i by a pushout) and $Ci\rightarrow Ci/CA = X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence (Hatcher 0.17).  If Mi is the mapping cylinder, then (Mi, A) is good and gives the LES.  More specifically, one sees in this manner that the natural map $H_*(X,A) \rightarrow H_* (X/A, A/A)$ is an isomorphism for any cofibration.

Comment: I just noticed that my previous comment is more or less what May says in Section 14.2 of his book; he's working with an arbitrary generalized homology theory.

Answer (score 5):

Call a pair $(X,A)$ *cofibred* if $A$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and the inclusion $A\subseteq X$ has the homotopy extension property. I will produce examples of $(i)$ a good pair which is not cofibred, and $(ii)$ a cofibred pair which is not good. Neither example is my own, but they are not as well known as they should be.

**A good pair which is not cofibred**. Let $\Omega$ be an uncountable cardinal and consider the Tychonoff cube $I^\Omega$. The inclusion $0\hookrightarrow I^\Omega$ of the origin is evidently a strong deformation retract. Therefore the pair $(I^\Omega,\{0\})$ is good. However the pair is not cofibred. For if it were the point $0$ would be the zero-set of a continuous function $\varphi:I^\Omega\rightarrow I$, and this point is [not even a G$_\delta$-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576045/the-origin-is-not-a-zero-set-in-an-uncountable-product-of-intervals).

*Discussion*: The space $I^\Omega$ is a locally contractible compact $T_2$ space (which is separable when $\Omega\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$). As such it serves as a counterexample both in the category of all spaces and in the category of compactly generated spaces. The fact that the deformation retract of $I^\Omega$ onto $0$ can be chosen to fix $0$ at all times means that there is a homotopy equivalence of pairs $(I^\Omega,0)\simeq(0,0)$. Stated another way this reads; being well-pointed is not an invariant of pointed-homotopy type.

**A cofibred pair which is not good**. Sergey Melikhov describes [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87387/well-pointed-space-which-is-not-locally-contractible) Borsuk's example of a 2-dimensional, compact, contractible metric space $M$ possessing the singularity of Mazurkiewicz. The original example is found on page 152 of Borsuk's book *The Theory of Retracts*. Our counterexample is its subspace, and here are the salient properties of $M$ which we will need to find it.

$1)$ $M$ is an absolute retract for metric spaces. Consequently, if $U\subset M$ is any open subset and $x\in U$ any point, then the inclusion $x\hookrightarrow U$ is a cofibration.

$2)$ $M$ is locally contractible in the sense that for any open $U\subseteq M$ and any $x\in U$, there is an open $V\subseteq U$ with $x\in V$ for which the inclusion $V\hookrightarrow U$ is null-homotopic. Still, $M$ is not a countable union of its contractible proper subsets. Since $M$ is a compact metric space it is separable and first-countable, and consequently $M$ has points which do not possess a base of contractible neighbourhoods.

We turn to our construction. Fix any point $x_0\in M$ which does not have a base of contractible neighbourhoods and let $\{U_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ be a neighbourhood base at $x_0$. We can assume that the $U_n$'s form a decreasing sequence of noncontractible open sets.

*Claim*: There is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(U_n,x_0)$ is not a good pair.

This is verified by exhaustion. If $(U_1,x_0)$ is not a good pair, then we are done. Thus suppose that $(U_1,x_0)$ *is* a good pair. This means that $x_0$ has a contractible neighbouhood $V_1\subseteq U_1$. Then using the fact that the $U_n$'s form a neighbourhood base at $x_0$ we find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $U_n\subseteq V_1$. Now repeat the argument with $(U_n,x_0)$. If this pair is good we stop, and if not we have $U_m\subseteq V_n\subseteq U_n$, where $m>n$ and $V_n$ is a contractible neighbourhood of $x$.

Now, this process must terminate to yield a non-good pair. For if it did not we could re-enumerate the $V_n$'s and $U_n$'s to obtain a sequence $\{V_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ of contractible open neighbourhoods of $x_0$ such that $V_n\subseteq U_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Because $\{U_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ is a base at $x_0$, so would be $\{V_n\}_\mathbb{N}$, and this contradicts the fact that $x_0$ does not have a base of contractible neighbourhoods. $\square$

The end result is the presence of a noncontractible open $X\subseteq M$ which contains $x_0$, and is such that $(X,x_0)$ is not good. But $X$, being an open subset of an absolute retract, is itself an absolute neighbourhood retract. As was discussed above, a consequence of this is that the inclusion $x_0\hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration. Thus we have obtained a cofibred pair $(X,x_0)$ which is not good.

*Discussion*: The space $X$ is a locally contractible (in the above sense) separable 2-dimensional metric space. In any case $(X,x_0)$ is a counterexample in the categories of all spaces, compactly generated spaces, and $\Delta$-generated spaces.

Note that $X$ has the pointed homotopy type of a countable, finite-dimensional CW complex. Thus not even in the category of well-pointed spaces is being a good pair an invariant of pointed homotopy type.