# Neighborhood deformation retracts vs cofibrations

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I got really confused over the different notions of *neighborhood deformation retracts* and *cofibrations* one can find in various sources on algebraic topology and alike, so I would really appreciate, if someone could help me out. I did not find a question immediately linking the various notions, so I hope this is not a duplicate.

I assume $A \subseteq X$ to be a closed subspace. How do the following definitions correlate?

> **Definition 1**
> $A$ is a strong neighborhood deformation retract of $X$, if there is an open neighborhood $A \subseteq N \subseteq X$, such that the inclusion $i:A \rightarrow X$ has a retraction $r:N \rightarrow A$ with $ri = 1_A$ and $ir \sim 1_N$ via a homotopy $H:N\times[0,1] \rightarrow N$ satisfying $H(a,t) = a$ for $a\in A$.
>
> **Definition 2**
> $A$ is a neighborhood deformation retract of $X$, if there is an open neighborhood $A \subseteq N \subseteq X$, such that the inclusion $i:A \rightarrow X$ has a retraction $r:N \rightarrow A$ with $ri = 1_A$ for which there is a homotopy $H:N\times[0,1] \rightarrow X$ satisfying $H(x,0)=x$, $H(x,1)\in A$, and $H(a,t) = a$ for $x\in N$, $a\in A$, and $t\in I$.
>
> **Definition 3**
> $(X,A)$ is a NDR-pair (ncatlab) or $A$ is a neighborhood deformation retract of $X$ (wikipedia), if there are maps $h:I\times X \rightarrow X$ and $u:X \rightarrow I$, which satisfy
>
> - $h(a,t) = a$
> - $h(x,0) = x$
> - $u^{-1}(\{0\}) = A$
> - $h(x,t)\in A$ if $u(x)<t$.
>
> [ncatlab section 3](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+retract#in_topological_spaces) or [wikipedia, cofibrations and NDRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract)

Ncatlab mentions that the canonical inclusion $i:A \rightarrow X$ has a homotopy left inverse, if and only if it has a retraction $r:X \rightarrow A$ (ie. $ri = 1_A$). This remark confuses me, as in my understanding this would make $A$ a deformation retract of $X$ instead of a neighborhood deformation retract.

Wikipedia mentions at the same place as definition 4 that it is equivalent to the following definition of cofibration.

> **Definition 4**
> The inclusion $i:A \rightarrow X$ is a cofibration, if it has the homotopy extension property, ie. for any morphism $f:A\times I \cup X\times \{1\}\rightarrow T$ there exists a (not necessarily unique) extension $\tilde{f}:I \times X \rightarrow T$ along the inclusion $j:A\times I \cup X\times \{0\} \rightarrow X\times I$, meaning that $f = \tilde{f}i$. [wikipedia homotopy extension property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_extension_property)

According to [Groth Prop. 3](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Emgroth/teaching/htpy13/Section08.pdf) being a cofibration is equivalent to $j:A\times I\cup X\times\{0\} \rightarrow X\times I$ having a retraction.

My initial goal was to show that, given a closed neighborhood deformation retract $i:A \rightarrow X$, the map $j:A\times I\cup X\times\{0\} \rightarrow I \times X$ is a deformation retract. Instead, I managed to confuse myself to an extent, which made it impossible for me to find relations between the four definitions given here, yet alone to approach my initial problem. I really hope someone can help me out. Regardless, huge thanks to anyone who read up until here!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We start by proving

$(4)\Rightarrow(3)$ Taking $f$ as the identity we get a retraction $r:X\times I\rightarrow A\times I\cup X\times0$. Fixing one such we set $u:X\rightarrow I$ to be the map

$$u(x)=\sup_{t\in I}|t-pr_2\circ r(x,0)|,\qquad x\in X.$$

Also let $h:X\times I\rightarrow X$ be the homotopy

$$h(x,t)=pr_1\circ r(x,t),\qquad t\in I,x\in X.$$

Then all required properties are immediate. $\blacksquare$

$(3)\Rightarrow(4)$ We have the maps $u,h$ and need to define a retraction $r$ to the inclusion $A\times I\cup X\times\{0\}\subseteq X\times I$. This is given by

$$r(x,t)=\begin{cases}(h(t,x),0)&t\leq u(x)\\
(h(t,x),t-u(x))& t\geq u(x)\end{cases}$$

You check easily that it is well-defined. Given $f:A\times I\cup X\times 0\rightarrow T$ the extension is now $\widetilde f=fr:X\times I\rightarrow T$. $\blacksquare$

Thus $(3)$ and $(4)$ are equivalent and imply that the inclusion of the closed subspace $A\subseteq X$ is a cofibration.

$(3)\Rightarrow(2)$ Put $N=u^{-1}[0,1)$ and let $H=h|_{N\times I}$. $\blacksquare$

The last implication is not reversible in general. It turns out the presence of the function $u$ is extremely important. However, we can go backwards if we assume the additional condition

$(\ast)$: There is a map $v:X\rightarrow I$ such that $A=v^{-1}(0)$ and $N=v^{-1}[0,1)$.

Evidently $(3)\Rightarrow(2)+(\ast)$.

$(2)+(\ast)\Rightarrow(3)$ Define a retraction $r:X\times I\rightarrow A\times I\cup X\times 0$ by

$$r(x,t)=\begin{cases}
(x,t)&x\in v^{-1}(0)\\
(h(x,t/2v(x)),0)&x\in v^{-1}(0,1/2]\;\text{and}\;t\leq2v(x)\\
(h(x,1),t+2v(x))&x\in v^{-1}(0,1/2]\;\text{and}\;2v(x)\leq t<1\\
(h(x,2(1-v(x))t),0)&x\in v^{-1}[1/2,1)\\
(x,0)&x\in v^{-1}(1).\quad\blacksquare
\end{cases}$$

At this stage we have shown that $(2)+(\ast)\Leftrightarrow(3)\Leftrightarrow(4)$ are all equivalent. Note that sufficient conditions for $(\ast)$ to hold are given by any of the following.

1. $X$ is perfectly normal and $A\subseteq X$ is closed.
2. $X$ is normal and $A\subseteq X$ is a closed $G_\delta$-set.
3. $X$ is Tychonoff and $A\subseteq X$ is a compact $G_\delta$-set.

Thus $(X,A)$ having any of these properties is sufficient for $(3)\Rightarrow(4)$ with no apriori knowledge of $v$. Note that every metric space (so every manifold) and every CW complex is perfectly normal. A $G_\delta$-set is a subset which is the intersection of countably many open sets.

Now, $(3)\Rightarrow(2)$ and obviously $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$, with neither implication reversible in general. Unfortunately there are also no direct implications between $(1)$ and $(3)$, as we have [counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854281/good-pair-vs-cofibration) to the contrary.

As for your last question, if $(X,A)$ is a closed NDR pair (def. 3), then we have a retraction $r:X\times I\rightarrow A\times I\cup X\times 0$, and a homotopy

$$H_s(x,t)=(pr_1\circ r(x,st),(1-s)t+s pr_2\circ r(x,t))$$

Thus the inclusion of $A\times I\cup X\times 0$ into the cylinder is a strong deformation retraction in this case.

Comment: Thank you so so much! This fills quite a hole in my current understanding of algebraic topology...

Comment: In your proof 3) => 4), isn‘t $t > u(x)$ but $h(t, x) \notin A$ possible if for example $t < 1$?

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition of $u$? $r$ being a retraction means that $r(0,x)=(0,x)$, so $pr_1(r(0,x))=0$.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the required homotopy $ir\simeq id_N$ in $3)\Rightarrow 2)\Rightarrow 1$ is valued in $N$ for all times. Could someone please explain to me why the homotopy is a deformation of $N$ to $A$ in $N$ and not merely a deformation of $N$ to $A$ in $X$?

Comment: Consulting Aguilar, Gitler and Prieto, their definition of strong deformation retract (4.11.1) does not require that the homotopy takes values in the neighborhood, the paths are allowed to wander through the ambient space X. This is at first glance a weaker condition than Def. 2 quoted in the post.

Comment: This is an open question here, so if you have an answer please post it there as well. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232269/a-question-about-cofibrations

Comment: @HDB There was a mistake in the original formulation. My apologies to anyone who did not notice it. I wrote this three years ago, and I guess I learned something in that time.

Comment: @PatrickNicodemus This has been fixed. I answered the question you linked by providing counterexamples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854281/good-pair-vs-cofibration).